# what is trial in my experiment?

Tags: experiment-design, terminology

I have a basic question about the exact meaning of trial in experimental designs.
My experiment includes presenting three rhythmic patterns (each consisting of 5 sounds) to participants and they're supposed to say which one is different from the other two and then we go to the next three rhythms and so on. Now I wanna know if the three presentations at the end of which rating happens are the trial or each of the three rhythms or every single sound in each rhythmic sequence.
In fact, I haven't got the exact meaning of trial and I would very much appreciate it if anybody could clarify it.

Answer (score 2):

*Trial* here is the single experimental unit, we could say the "atom of the experiment", which leads to one observed value each. So here it is

> ... presenting three rhythmic patterns (each consisting of 5 sounds)
> to participants and they're supposed to say which one is different
> from the other two ...

which results in one observed value, which here is an identifier of the different one.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So just to make sure, you're saying that in my experiment, every three rhythms at the end of which rating happens is considered one trial. Right?
If so what do we call each of the three rhythmic sequences and also each single sound in each rhythm?

Comment: Why do these *parts* of the trial need a specific name?

Comment: I don’t mean they should necessarily have a specific name. I just thought maybe they’re called in a specific way like the trial itself.